# Creating front end for sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very large sql database. I want to create a sql database front end where users can input date or other criteria such as box number, wallet numbers to view a report. Since I do not have any programming knowledge, I need to learn a language all by my self. I just want to know which language will be best for me to create a front end for sql database?

Comment: It depends on you. PHP, ASPX or others. But I think php is good for open source language

Comment: as Aldi already said, it really depends on you - there is a variety on languages capable talking to your SQL database. From my point of view PHP is really simple to get an early grasp of, because there are handy features like type conversion. Other languages require the coder to define the type of data a variable should store. PHP does not.

Comment: Microsoft .Net (vb.net or c#.net) work very well with SQL Server databases. You can download c#/vb 2012 express edition for free and watch tutorials on how to create a basic UI that interacts with your SQL Server database. That would be a good starting point.

Comment: @SelectDistinct & Aldi Unanto: which one should be easy to learn and use? PHP or C#?

Comment: I like you had no experience whatsoever of programming 2 years ago, only SQL. I went with .Net as it was more common in my place of work. As far is PHP is concerned I cannot comment as I have no experience in it. Although if you are planning on using SQL Server perhaps Microsoft.Net is more compatible as they are both Microsoft developed?

Comment: According to me, .Net is best among best.All inbuilt controls.Just drag and drop knowledge is enough.Moreover few controls like repeater,datagrid,etc with pagination,sorting will be most useful in development.And also (reference to above comment) both are microsoft products.So no need to worry at all.In cod behind if you are unaware of c#,use vb.net..its very easy..